# How to test fork of fastlane plugin

Tags: plugins, fastlane

I have made a fork of a fastlane plugin and made some changes in the local clone. How do I test the changes?

In the plugin dir with my changes I have done

```
$ bundle install
$ rake install
```

I have a project that uses the plugin and have tried to change the Pluginfile from

```
gem "fastlane-plugin-msbuild"
```

to

```
gem "fastlane-plugin-msbuild", path: "../../github/fastlane-plugin-msbuild"
```

In the project dir I have then done a

```
$ bundle install
```

and the forked plugin from the local filesystem is picked up fine. This is also reflected in the Gemfile.lock

In the forked plugin I have updated the version number to be able to track it.

But when I run fastlane

```
$ bundle exec fastlane android beta
```

the section with "Used plugins" still state the old version number and I can see from execution that the original plugin is used.

What am I doing wrong? What is the normal way of testing fastlane plugins locally?

I am on macOS Sierra (10.12.6).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically correct. A couple of notes:

`rake install` installs a local copy of your modified plugin under `$GEM_HOME`. You should be able to use your modified plugin this way without making any changes to the `Pluginfile` in your project. But then you have to `rake install` each time you make changes. Modifying the `Pluginfile` as you have ignores anything from `$GEM_HOME`, so `rake install` is not necessary.

You have a `$` before `gem` in the excerpts from your `Pluginfile`. I assume that's just transcription, and that you're not using a `$` in the `Pluginfile`. If you are, you should remove it.

Assuming that's all correct, you should pick up the uninstalled gem from the local fork.

Is it possible you also have the plugin gem declared somewhere else, e.g. in your `Gemfile`?

You can also try running `bundle update`, which will update all gems in your `Gemfile.lock` to the most recent versions, depending on the requirements in your `Gemfile` and `Pluginfile`. This will also take the gem from the local fork, but it should also work with `bundle install`.

The short answer to your question is that you're doing it right. I'm not sure why it's not working.

Comment: Yes the $ signs you mention was my typo, now removed. Thank you for the explanation, it helps with my understanding. I had hoped I did something wrong.

Comment: I additionally had to delete the ~/.fastlane folder to get this working. I assume it had a cached version.

Answer (score 2):

With the help of the insights from Jimmy Dee I finally tracked down the problem: fastlane had its own set of gems installed in ~/.fastlane

This seems to be the default place fastlane wants to put its stuff when using the installer. I probably have had multiple installations of fastlane. The one I thought I used was in /usr/local and that is where bundle was and where my plugin went when I did af rake install.

I simply removed the ~/.fastlane directory entirely and it worked.

Comment: I suspect you've installed Fastlane from Homebrew or something similar, rather than RubyGems. That build basically doesn't work with plugins, as far as I understand. Do you also have gem "fastlane" in your Gemfile? I think that should take precedence, but it's possible that it's picking up the Homebrew build anyway. Glad you got it working.